# CSS or JS make vert scrollbar appear only when scrolling

Tags: javascript, css, scrollbar

Anyone know how to make the verticle scrollbar appear only when scrolling with CSS or JS?

Thanks

Comment: The only (cross-browser) way is a custom JS scroll bar. Those can be done by making your own, or you can [search for one](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+scroll+bar) online

Comment: <scratches head> If you're already scrolling, doesn't that imply that there's already a scrollbar?

Comment: Good point j08691, may be the boss woman will go for it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be done using CSS or JavaScript/jQuery.

#### Here are a few examples:

```js
// JavaScript Example
document.querySelector('.jsExample').addEventListener('mouseenter', function(e){
  e.target.style.overflow = 'auto';
}, false);

document.querySelector('.jsExample').addEventListener('mouseleave', function(e){
  e.target.style.overflow = 'hidden';
}, false);


// jQuery Example
$('.jQueryExample').hover(
  function() { // Run on hover/mouseenter
    $(this).css('overflow', 'auto');
  },
  function() { // Run on mouseleave
    $(this).css('overflow', 'hidden');
  }
);
```

```css
/* CSS Example */
.cssExample { overflow: hidden; }
.cssExample:hover { overflow: auto; }


/* Unimportant CSS just to setup examples */
.cssExample, .jsExample, .jQueryExample {
  background: #EEE;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 4em;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.cssExample::after, .jsExample::after, .jQueryExample::after {
  display: block;
  content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="cssExample">CSS Example</div>
<div class="jsExample">JavaScript Example</div>
<div class="jQueryExample">jQuery Example</div>
```

With the JavaScript or jQuery versions you could do more stuff like showing a custom scrollbar or attach the hover event listener to an element that covers the right 100px of the scrolling element so that the scroll bar only appears when the mouse moves to that side. Just a couple of examples.

Comment: Do you know how to write this in vanilla JS? Don't want to add thousands of lines of jQuery to simply show/hide a scrollbar. Waste of space, bandwidth, processing prover for both the user and the server.

Comment: Yes. I cleaned up the examples and added a 'pure' JavaScript version as well.

Comment: Thank you! I just tested it, and it doesn't work as I expected (but that's not your issue or to the topic). If say text is selected after finger is held down for 200 ms on a touch device, you have to hold for 100 ms before you can scroll. So every other time, you'll trigger the "select text" instead.